# web.config rule to match a parent page and any descendents

Tags: asp.net, xml, redirect, web-config

I'm not familiar with asp.net but need to add some redirects to the `web.config`. I added some examples of what I'm looking to match and my attempt of creating a rule:

```
<!--

   URLs to match:

   - example.com/parent-page
   - example.com/parent-page/child
   - example.com/parent-page/child/grandchild

-->

<rule name="parent-page/*" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^parent-page/(.*)"/>
  <action redirectType="Permanent" type="Redirect" url="/new-parent-page/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

I don't have the environment setup to test this at the moment so I'm wondering if this looks right?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the correct rule:

```
<rule name="parent-page/*" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^parent-page(.*)"/>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="new-parent-page{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>
```